# Redirect old domain to new domain with Nginx, with same subdomain and URI

Tags: nginx

We have two domains that point to the same server. One we've branded around more recently so we want to have it so that the URL changes from old_domain.com to new_domain.com.

I also want to have it so that the subdomain and URI the user initially entered is used as well.

For example -

```
https://beta.old_domain.com/my_profile

redirects to

https://beta.new_domain.com/my_profile
```

I've tried a couple solutions but am struggling with getting it to work. The latest I was this -

*/etc/nginx/sites-available/old_domain.com*

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name old_domain.com;

  if ($host ~ (.*)\.old_domain\.com(.*)) {
    set $subdomain $1;
    return 301 $subdomain.new_domain.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it by creating two different `server` blocks, one for the main domain and another to redirect requests on subdomains:

```
server {
    server_name old-domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://new-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>\w+)\.old-domain\.com$;
    return 301 $scheme://$name.new-domain.com/;
}
```

Comment: This is a clean solution and after the old domain is gone, can be removed from the configuration easily.